# R igraph cluster nodes with the same colour (feature)

Tags: r, igraph

```
# example data
library(igraph)
links <- cbind.data.frame(from = rep("A", 6),
                      to = LETTERS[1:6],
                      weight = rep((1:3), each =2))

nodes <- nodes <- cbind.data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:6],
                               feature = rep((1:3), each =2))

net <- graph_from_data_frame(d = links, vertices = nodes, directed = T) 
V(net)$color <- V(net)$feature
plot(net, vertex.size=30, edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

This is what I get:
[image]

What I want is to cluster the same colored nodes together, something similar as shown in the figure below. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the option `mark.groups` in `plot` could help

```
plot(net,mark.groups = split(V(net)$name,V(net)$color))
```

which gives

[image]